# Issue returning object

Tags: reactjs, routes, backend

I'm still new to learning how to work backend and I have been running into this issue where instead of displaying the questions it throws an error (The routes are being tested via Thunder Client) here's the code below:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Question Data
const Questions = require('../../models/questions-data.json')


router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
  try{
    const question = await Questions.find()
    return res.send(question)
  } 
  catch(error){
  return res.status(500).send({"error": error})
}
})
module.exports = router;
```

As I stated as of right now the code just sends the error message rather than displaying the questions and I can't figure out why, any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Also here is how the question object is structured:

```
question:string;
options:string[];
answer:string;
```

Comment: You say it sends an error message, but fail to tell us what the error message is. Please [edit] your question to include that error as text.

Comment: Well the Error message is what the res.status(500) is, I should have specified that. Im just confused as to why the top portion of the code isn't executing

Comment: Well, [Areeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414657/215552) sheds a fair amount of light on that subject...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Questions is of JSON format, `find()` method will throw an error. `find()` method is used on arrays, not objects.

Also, you wrote `req.send(question)` instead of `res.send(question)`.

Try:

```
return res.send(Questions)
```

if it is an object, and see if the response gives the object.
If `Questions` is an array of objects, and you want to operate on it with `find`, you should give a condition which will return the first element that matches that condition.

```
 return res.send(questions.find(element=>element.someKey === 'someValue'))
```

Comment: @CH Please don't share code in a comment. Instead, update your question with any code you wish to share.

Comment: @Areeb Thanks for the explanation, returning Questions worked however I have 1 more additional question how would I return only specific attributes in this case only the question and its options?

Comment: @CH you can try `res.send({question: Questions.question, options: Questions.options})`
What we do here is we send an object in the response, having two keys - `question` and `options`. `question` has a value of what `Questions` object has under the `question` key, and same goes for the `options` key.

Comment: @Areeb That didn't seem to work it just returned an empty JSON